# Creating backspace on iOS calculator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, string, calculator

I'm trying to add a backspace button to remove the last entered digit in a calculator, but I can't seem to get it. Here is what I've tried:

```
-(IBAction)backspacePressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSMutableString *string = (NSMutableString*)[display text];

    int length = [string length];

    NSString *temp = [string substringFromIndex:length-1];

    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp]];

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what if the last was not a digit? what if it is an operand?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `[string substringToIndex:length-1]` instead of `[string substringFromIndex:length-1]`.

Comment: @Jason He want to delete the last character, not the first one

Comment: My mistake, I must have misread the question.  Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `subStringToIndex` method instead of `subStringFromIndex`

```
NSString *temp = [string substringToIndex:length-1];
```

Comment: +1 for editing the post AND getting the right answer in within 20 seconds of the other guy :)