# CS193p-Adding backspace to a calculator

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cs193p

I recently started following the online course on iPhone development from Stanford University on iTunes U.

I'm trying to do the homework assignments now for the first couple of lectures. I followed through the walkthrough where I built a basic calculator, but now I'm trying the first assignment and I can't seem to work it out. It's a follows:

> *Implement a “backspace” button for the user to press if they hit the wrong digit button. This is not intended to be “undo,” so if they hit
>   the wrong operation button, they are out of luck! It’s up to you to
>   decided how to handle the case where they backspace away the entire
>   number they are in the middle of entering, but having the display go
>   completely blank is probably not very user-friendly.*

I followed this: [Creating backspace on iOS calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591551/creating-backspace-on-ios-calculator)

So the code is

```
-(IBAction)backspacePressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSMutableString *string = (NSMutableString*)[display text];

    int length = [string length];

    NSString *temp = [string substringToIndex:length-1];

    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp]];

}
```

My question is shouldn't I check whether my last is a digit or operand? If operand, no execution and if digit, remove it...

Comment: Yes, you should check.  You obviously know you should check.  Why are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are several unnecessary steps in that code... And to answer your question, yes, you should check for an operand. Here is how I would write that method with a check:

```
NSString *text = [display text];
int length = [text length];
unichar c = [text characterAtIndex:length];
NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalCharacterSet];
if ([digits characterIsMember:c] || c == '.') {
    NSString *temp = [[display text] substringToIndex:length-1];
    [display setText:temp];
}
```

Comment: Ah good point. It's a pretty simple fix though, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also going through the fall 2011 class on iTunes U.

The walk through gives us an instance variable userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber so I just checked to see if that is YES.

```
- (IBAction)backspacePressed {
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
        if ([self.display.text length] > 1) {
            self.display.text = [self.display.text substringToIndex:[self.display.text length] - 1];
        } else {
            self.display.text = @"0";
            self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the approach taken by Joe_Schmoe, which is straightforward. (just remove characters in the dispaly until you reach the end).

If the user continues pressing 'Clear Error', I removed an item from the stack as well.

Comment: you could also use introspection right? Check whether it is kind of number, if so delete.. if it is a number do not do anything?

Answer (score 1):

I have just started on the course myself, this post is quite old now but my solution might help others, food for thought if nothing else:

```
- (IBAction)deletePressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *displayText = [display text];
    int length = [displayText length];
    if (length != 1) {
        NSString *newDisplayText = [displayText substringToIndex:length-1];
        [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newDisplayText]];
    } else {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
        NSString *newDisplayText = @"0";
        [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newDisplayText]];
    }
}
```